# Why does 11010100 << 1 equal 110101000, not 10101000?

Tags: java, bit-shift

Why when I try to shift bits for 11010100<sub>2</sub>, the result is 110101000<sub>2</sub>, not 10101000<sub>2</sub>.

```
int a = Integer.parseInt("11010100", 2) << 1;
```

I try to do this:

```
int a = (byte)(Integer.parseInt("11010100", 2) << 1);
```

But if the output value is greater than 128, everything goes into minus, which is logical.
How can I make that number of bits does not change?

Comment: Integer arithmetic is always done on `int`s or `long`s.

Comment: You are using integers, those are 32 bits long. Why would you expect the result to be truncated to 8 bits?

Comment: byte a = ... will fix it.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Let's take it one step at a time.

1. `Integer.parseInt("11010100", 2)` - this is the int value 212. This is, by the way, needless; you can just write: `0b11010100`.
2. `0b11010100 << 1` is the same as `0b110101000`, and is 424.
3. You then cast it to a byte: `(byte)(0b11010100 << 1)`. The bits beyond the first 8 all get lopped off, which leaves 0b10101000, which is -88. Minus, yes, because in java bytes are signed.
4. You then silently cast this -88 back up to int, as you assign it to an int value. It remains -88, which means all the top bits are all 1s.

Hence, the final value is `-88`.

If you want to see `168` instead (which is the exact same bits, but shown unsigned instead of signed), the usual trick is to use `& 0xFF`, which sets all bits except the first 8 to 0, thus guaranteeing a positive number:

```java
byte b = (byte) (0b11010100 << 1);
System.out.println(b); // -88. It is not possible to print 168 when printing a byte.
int asUnsigned = b & 0xFF;
System.out.println(asUnsigned); // 168.

// or in one go:

System.out.println(((byte) (0b11010100 << 1)) & 0xFF); // 168
```

Comment: He's storing the value in `int a`, so if you have `& 0xFF`, then you don't need to cast at all.  `int a = (0b11010100<< 1) & 0xFF;`

Answer (score 10):

If you want to set to 0 all bits higher than the bottom 8 bits, you can use bit-wise AND:

```
int a = (Integer.parseInt("11010100", 2) << 1) & 0xff;
System.out.println (Integer.toString(a,2));
```

Output:

```
10101000
```

Answer (score 6):

Try something like this:

```
int anInt = Integer.parseInt("11010100", 2) << 1;
int asUnsignedInt= Byte.toUnsignedInt((byte) anInt);
```

[toUnsignedInt](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Byte.html#toUnsignedInt(byte)) has been introduced in Java SE 8.